# Get number from specific line in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have line like this:

```
<action actionid="9717" script="other/yackal.lua" />
```

How do I get only numbers from "actionid="9717"".

2nd same but with:

```
uniqueid="9717"
```

3rd

```
<action fromaid="44850" toaid="44856" script="quests/reward.lua"/>
```

Is it possible to get all numbers from this?
I mean, 44850, 44851, 44852, ..., 44856. Also it should search for the fromaid and to aid, because I have lines with fromid and toid which should not be taken.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You could use a regex like `<action fromaid="(.*?)" toaid="(.*?)"` to find those lines fairly easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Regex to extract numbers after second word and between double quotes.

like `(<action )[a-z](=")(*?)(")`

I don't have notepad++ on my linux :(